How / where can one access the records made by ancient Hindu bureaucracies?
Modern bureaucracies (governments, corporates, religious orgs, etc) use various filing methods to preserve records of their key decisions. These records used to be on paper, but digital technology is now being used to various degrees.
My question is about old Hindu kingdoms and ashrams. By most narrations, these were big complex organizations with thousands of individuals and lasted thousands of years, if not longer. They must have kept records.
The question is, are these records available today? If yes, how to access them? If no, what happened to these records?
